# How to create dependency between releases in helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I have a following helmfile and I want for nexus, teamcity-server, nexus, hub to be depended on certificates chart

```
releases:
- name: certificates
  createNamespace: true
  chart: ./charts/additional-dep
  namespace: system
  values:
    - ./environments/default/system-values.yaml
    - ./environments/{{ .Environment.Name }}/system-values.yaml

- name: hub
  chart: ./charts/hub
  namespace: system
  values:
    - ./environments/default/system-values.yaml


- name: nexus
  chart: ./charts/nexus
  namespace: system
  values:
    - ./environments/default/system-values.yaml
    - ./environments/{{ .Environment.Name }}/system-values.yaml
  dependsOn:
  - certificates

- name: teamcity-server
  chart: ./charts/teamcity-server
  namespace: system
  values:
    - ./environments/default/system-values.yaml
    - ./environments/{{ .Environment.Name }}/system-values.yaml
  dependsOn:
  - certificates
```

I have tried to use dependsOn in helmfile.yaml, however it has resulted in errors

Answer (score 1):

Helmfile calls this functionality [`needs:`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dag-aware-installationdeletion-ordering-with-needs), so

```yaml
releases:
  - name: certificates
    ...

  - name: nexus
    needs:
      - certificates
    ...
```

This means the `certificates:` chart needs to be successfully installed before Helmfile will move on to `nexus` or `teamcity-server`.  This is specific to Helmfile, so you're allowed to `helm uninstall certificates` and Helm itself won't know about the dependency.  It also doesn't establish any sort of runtime dependency between the two charts, so if something happens later that causes `certificates` to fail, `nexus` and the other dependents won't be automatically stopped.