# Helm subcharts installation 1 after the other

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a requirement where i have multiple services to deploy. I have helm charts of all the separate services.
I want to install the parent chart and the dependencies in the order like : install next dependency only when the current dependent helm chart is installed and the pods are up.

Solution tried :
I have tried to add the dependencies in the Chart.yaml, but once we do helm install parent-chart, it starts the installation of all the dependent charts at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm wait till dependency deployment are ready on kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928861/helm-wait-till-dependency-deployment-are-ready-on-kubernetes)

Comment: @akathimi This clears up some things, but i am asking more about hooks with dependency type solution (if anything like that exists.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm Subchart order of execution in an umbrella chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492389/helm-subchart-order-of-execution-in-an-umbrella-chart)

Comment: I think "dependency" is the wrong term. If your parent chart must be installed first, and then the other charts must be installed after that, those other charts are **dependent** on the parent chart, not the other way around.

Comment: IME a typical Kubernetes style is to send everything into the cluster in one batch, and let pods crash and restart until all of the dependencies are available.  (This is easy to do, but can be hard to debug if it doesn't work.)  If you really have multiple applications, again IME, an umbrella chart is hard to use and maintain.  [How to create dependency between releases in helmfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75043730/how-to-create-dependency-between-releases-in-helmfile) is a slightly different tool but could address this as well.